# fetching a saved video from document directory to uiview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview

Here I need to fetch video from document directory to my view .I don't know how to fetch this .if you guys know please help me and provide any links you know.Thanks in advance

Comment: how about you make the minimum amount of effort?

Comment: What you are speaking.Actually my video is saving in document directory and I need to fetch that video to next view.how to do this.till now i didn't do any video based apps.so,please help me